# How to populate multi table data in jquery High-chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, highcharts

I am trying to fetch multiple table data with UNION ALL to high-chart with the following code, But i am unable to do that.

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");

$db->beginTransaction();

try{

$query = "SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks, DATE(date_column) AS daTe, 'class 1' AS class FROM table1 Group By DATE(date_column)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks, DATE(date_column) AS daTe, 'class 2' AS class FROM table2 Group By DATE(date_column)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(marks) AS marks, DATE(date_column) AS daTe, 'class 3' AS class FROM table3 Group By DATE(date_column)";
$done= $db->prepare($query);
$done->execute();
$display = '';
$row = $done->fetch()
    $result[] = $row;
      //$display .="{name:".$row->class.", data:".$row->marks.", date:".$row->daTe."},";

$db->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

[Table 1 (class 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX5CZ.png)

[Table 2 (class 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRa26.png)

[Table 3 (class 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTO0E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been changed your query to get desired output.Result will look like the following table.

[image]

The query gives like the following result.

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");

$db->beginTransaction();
try{    
    $query = "SELECT dr.dates, SUM(a.marks) AS t1marks, SUM(b.marks) AS t2marks, SUM(c.marks) AS t3marks  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(date_column)) AS dates FROM `table1`
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(date_column)) FROM `table2`
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(date_column)) FROM `table3`) AS dr 
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS a ON dr.dates = DATE(a.date_column) 
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON dr.dates = DATE(b.date_column)
    LEFT JOIN table3 AS c ON dr.dates = DATE(c.date_column)
    GROUP BY dr.dates ORDER BY dates ASC";
    $done= $db->prepare($query);
    $done->execute();
    $rows = $done->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dates = $t1marks = $t2marks = $t3marks = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $dates[] = $row['dates'];
        $t1marks[] = $row['t1marks'] == null ? 0 : (int) $row['t1marks'];
        $t2marks[] = $row['t2marks'] == null ? 0 : (int) $row['t2marks'];
        $t3marks[] = $row['t3marks'] == null ? 0 : (int) $row['t3marks'];
    }

    $output = json_encode( array( array( 'data' => $t1marks, 'name'  => 'class 1'),
        array( 'data' => $t2marks, 'name'  => 'class 2'),
        array( 'data' => $t3marks, 'name'  => 'class 3')
     ) );   

    $db->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <div id="container" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script>

   Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    xAxis: { categories: <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?> },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        line: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      enableMouseTracking: false
    }
    },

    series: <?php echo $output; ?>,    

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                   layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As per fiddle the following no of elements in the following arrays should match.

[image]

Either we can add null or zero for non matching column elements. Here i added 0 for an elegant look for graph. Other wise lines will break in between values.

Output graph as per your input..

[image]

Comment: its showing multiple tables on one line .

Comment: so u expect 3 graph for 3 tables?

Comment: No, I mean its displaying all classes ( class 1, class 2, class 3) on the same line while every class or table have different values related to date.

Comment: can u share sample data for 3 tables..

Comment: question edited with sample data of 3 tables.

Comment: @Billa i updated ans with your input data..whenever a class doesn't have a data on a X axis date it would show 0..so classes are overlapping.Otherwise it will sj=how some data

Comment: sorry sir, but with some dates it gives wrong graph data. does it have conflict with other dates?

Comment: Your expectation is to show sum of each class's mark in graph right?